# Input type Password not working autocomplete="off" using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have used `autocomplete="off"` but not working in password input please check below atteched my demo code.

```
  <form name="testfrm" ng-submit="test(testfrm)" autocomplete="off">
       <input type="password" id="passwordFiled" name="test" autocomplete="off"  required>
       <button type="submit" class="btn"> test </button>
  </form>
```

Please let me know how to disabled autocomplete for password filed

Comment: Configure your browser to not store passwords then? Don’t try to mess with how I want to handle _my_ passwords in _my_ browser. Forcing users to handle things are certain way, just because you think it was the right one, does not actually increase security; rather often probably the contrary.

Comment: @CBroe

Yes man you are right, but if any solution for autocomplete off in your side please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a name-changer function for the password field, it can be a possible solution, here's the code I tried:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            // Returns random string based on 32 different characters and 4 dashes ("-")
            function string_generator() {
                var str = function() {
                   return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
            };
            return (str() + str() + "-" + str() + "-" + str() + "-" + str() + "-" + str() + str() + str());
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#passwordField").attr("name", string_generator());
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="testfrm" ng-submit="test(testfrm)">
            <input type="password" id="passwordField" name="test" autocomplete="off" required>
            <button type="submit" class="btn"> test </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it works (if it doesn't work, please check the password-field **id**, because in my code is "*passwordField*", while in your is "*passwordFiled*")

Anyway, if you need the original name *test* as the url variable, this answer is supposed to be useless